# sum of mutually exclusive subset

Tags: algorithms

I have to determine that it is **possible or not** that for a given X and K 
we can partition a set X into non empty mutually exclusive K subset such that sum of each subset is equal.
I have tried a lot. Please help me out.
How can we check it.?
e.g :-
$X= \{1,2,4,5,6\}$, $K=3$   possible $\{\{1,5\}, \{2,4\}, \{6\}\}$ sum of each set is $6$
$X=\{1,2,4,5,7\}$, $K=3$   not possible

Comment: Do you have to do this for a specific list of examples or do you want to find a general result?

Comment: @quid i want general result.

Comment: One obvious necessary condition is that the sum of $X$ is divisible by $K$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael it is but not satisfying all cases

Comment: You won't find a simple necessary and sufficient condition.  Even for $k=2$ the problem is NP-complete (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: @RobertIsrael but size of **1 ≤ K ≤ 8**

Answer (score 1):

Given an $n$-tuple $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} $ of positive integers and any vector $
S = [s_1, \ldots, s_k]$  of nonnegative integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^k s_i = \sum_{x \in X} x$, let $F_m(S)$ be the statement that $X_m = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$ can be partitioned into sets with sums $s_1, \ldots, s_k$.
Then $$F_m(S) = \bigvee_{i = 1}^k F_{m-1}(S - x_m e_i) $$
where $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard unit vector ($1$ in position $i$, all else $0$).  This allows an algorithm for determining $F_m(S)$.

EDIT: Here $\bigvee$ denotes "or".  We omit all terms where $S - x_m e_i$ has
a negative entry.
Note also that $F_m(S)$ is symmetric in $S$, so we may sort all the $S - x_m e_i$ in, say, increasing order.

For example, take $k = 3$ and $X = \{1,2,3,4,5,5,7,9\}$.  We want 
$ F_{8}(12,12,12)$.  The equation (with $x_8 = 9$) says $$F_8(12,12,12) = F_7(3,12,12) \; or \; F_7(12,3,12) \; or \; F_7(12,12,3) = F_7(3,12,12) $$  because all these are permutations of that one term.  Next, with $x_7 = 7$,
$$F_7(3,12,12) = F_6(3,5,12)\; or\; F_6(3,12,5) = F_6(3,5,12)$$
Next, with $x_6 = 5$,
$$F_6(3,5,12) = F_5(3,0,12) \; or \; F_5(3,5,7) = F_5(0,3,12) \; or \; F_5(3,5,7)$$
Here we have two possibilities to consider. 
Next, with $x_5 = 5$, 
$$\eqalign{
F_5(0,3,12) & = F_4(0,3,7)\cr
F_5(3,5, 7) &= F_4(0,3,7) \; or\; F_4(2,3,5)\cr}$$ 
etc.  Eventually you should get to $F_1(0,0,1)$ which is true...

Comment: could you please elaborate.i didn't get it.